# Spring Boot OpenAPI 3.0 Error Handling on Specific Endpoints

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, springfox

I have a little question for you. I have a spring boot app that has some authorization mechanism, meaning that some endpoints under `/private` path requires some priviliges.

I've already written this feature, if there is an authorization problem my controller advice returns appropriate 403 forbidden message to client.

My question starts here,

If I put the `@ApiResponse` annotation at the controller advice, the generated OpenAPI spec contains 403 error for every endpoint. Naturally, I don't want to see message 'This endpoint could give 403 error' on my public endpoints and also I don't want to add `@ApiResponse` annotation to all of my private endpoints as you can guess.

Is there any way to, tell OpenAPI spec generator to;

"I have a exception (for this example 403) I define the exception handler at in controller advice with appropriate `@ApiResponse` but include that error on endpoint's spec if an only if that endpoint will throws this exception."

Thanks in advance.